# How to parse japanese char (utf8?) from imap_fetchbody?

Tags: php, utf-8, imap

I am pulling down an email which has english, chinese and japanese in the email.
I was using PHP/EZComponents to do this, but a certain japanese char was just not coming through so I am switching to php imap_* funcs to see if they will work.

This is what I have below, and the output I am getting. I need to decode this somehow... I know this has been well (read:overly/chaotically) documented all over the web, but I dont have time to earn a PHD in this right now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$hn='{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$inbox = imap_open($hn,$username,$password,CL_EXPUNGE);

foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        $ov = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $msg = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
       var_dump($msg);

  // doesnt work... .. but right idea?
  // var_dump( utf8_decode($msg) ); 

}
```

PARTIAL OUTPUT:

```
<font face=3D"Arial"><span lang=3D"EN-US" style=3D"font-size:10.5pt"><br></=
span></font><font color=3D"navy" face=3D"MS Gothic"><span lang=3D"JA" style=
=3D"font-size:10.5pt">=CC=EC=9A=DD=A4=AC=A4=A4=A4=A4=A4=AB=A4=E9=A1=A2</spa=
n></font></p><p style=3D"margin-right:0pt;margin-bottom:12pt;margin-left:0p=
t">




<font color=3D"navy" face=3D"MS Gothic"><span lang=3D"JA" style=3D"font-siz=
e:10.5pt"><br></span></font></p><p style=3D"margin-right:0pt;margin-bottom:=
12pt;margin-left:0pt"><font color=3D"navy" face=3D"MS Gothic"><span lang=3D=
"JA" style=3D"font-size:10.5pt">xxend</span></font></p>
```

Comment: Nope, `utf8_decode` is not what you want. You need to fetch the email headers, parse them, figure out the message's transport encoding and/or character set (which is denoted in the header), then decode the transport encoding into normal text with the right method and/or convert it from any non-UTF-8 encoding to UTF-8 if necessary using `iconv`.

Comment: If the e-mail was all in UTF8 it should have all encoded correctly, if it didn't, then the character will have been imported from another character set, (it would be numbered differently) so it would display as a different character in UTF8. If the letter is 2 random letters long though, try utf8_decode.

Comment: I don't have the time to look into this in detail, but here's a paste of (parts of) an old throwaway script that processed specific email attachments: http://pastebin.com/5438Test. It does not deal with your specific problem, but it does deal to some degree with content encoding. You'd have to flesh this out a bit. Hope it helps.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-qprint.php

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem employed **imap_fetchbody** function to get the mail body.

I found that the string get from imap_fetchbody was converted to [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) string automatically.

I resolved this issue by using **imap_qprint** function to convert the fetched string body into correct one.